# How to improve inner_hits in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two ES_TYPEs in my_index

1. user
2. user_property

One is defined as parent (user) and another as child (user_property)

user_property has following mapping:

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/user_property
{
   "user_property": {
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "keyword",
         },
         "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get all users having some properties (say property1, property2) along with their properties value, so to do this I create following query with **inner_hits** but query response time is exponentially large with inner_hits.

```
GET /my_index/user/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "user_property",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "property1"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                     "name": "inner_hits_1"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "user_property",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "property2"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                     "name": "inner_hits_2"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to reduce this time ?

Comment: please mention elatsicsearch version?

Comment: I am using  ES version  : 5.6.6